# IdentityServer4 usage of IdentityServerTools to create a token from within identity server

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi, api-authorization

I'm using IdentityServer4 and have a scenario where I need to initiate a call to a secured API during a password reset process. IdentityServer4 does provide `IdentityServerTools` for the purpose of calling a secured resource from an extensibility point, however there is currently no documentation or examples for the indented usage.

How does one go about creating the necessary token using the provided methods in `IdentityServerTools`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IdentityServerTools` is available from DI. Simply inject it into your class and call the method to create a client token.

https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/tools.html

Comment: I'm downvoting your answer. There's no documentation on how to use this Class. And the OP is asking specificly  " How does one go about creating the necessary token using the provided methods in IdentityServerTools? " Please provide an example.

Comment: Thank you very much for creating that documentation for us. Now it is clearer. I'm unable to vote up right now. I ask you to kindly edit your answer and include the link so I can up vote. (SO won't allow me to do so until it gets edited in some way)

Comment: See this blog for more information on how to use the IdentityServerTools class. https://www.strathweb.com/2017/10/self-issuing-an-identityserver4-token-in-an-identityserver4-service/